# Search images via google in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to implement searching images in my iOS app using google search. I found google objective-c API (http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/). But not found examples for searching images. Maybe anyone already made something like this?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: this answer is out of context as it is for custom search rather than the general google search

This might help you:
[Google Search Blog: Image results now available from the Custom Search API](http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.com/2012/02/image-results-now-available-from-custom.html)

Or if you want to skip the blog post completely:
[Google code: JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my github project https://github.com/PavelKatunin/GoogleImagesSearcher
It searches images via Google Api and presents them in UITableView.